# PHP self validating form Checkboxes

Tags: php, validation, checkbox

I have a PHP self validating form that is validating all fields but not reporting the checkboxes to output. I can't seem to find an example to clarify. Please help!

```
 //make sure one of the services requested checkboxes are checked
$require_one_of = array('walkSale','RawSale','groomSale'); //names of posted checkboxes
$one_set=false;
foreach($require_one_of as $key){
 if(isset($_POST[$key])){
  $one_set=true;
  break;
}
}
if(!$one_set){
//error handling
 $reasonErr= "You forgot to select a Service!";
}
```

HTML form

```
 <fieldset id="field3">
  <legend id="legend3">Services Required:</legend>
  <hr />
  <input type="checkbox" name="walkSale" value="walkSale"
  <?php if(isset($_POST['walkSale'])) echo "checked='checked'";?> class="textfield"/>I'm looking for a Dog Walker!&nbsp;

  <input type="checkbox" name="RawSale" value="RawSale"
  <?php if(isset($_POST['RawSale'])) echo "checked='checked'";?> class="textfield"/>I'm looking to purchase Raw Food!&nbsp;

  <input type="checkbox" name="groomSale" value="groomSale"
  <?php if(isset($_POST['groomSale'])) echo "checked='checked'";?> class="textfield"/>I'm looking for a Dog Groomer!

  <span class="error">* <?php echo $reasonErr;?></span>

</fieldset>
```

Comment: Check out this link: http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-checkbox.html

Comment: Your form works. I don't see anything wrong with the form.

Comment: It will keep the selected checkboxes checked after submit but it is not reporting them in the output or to mysql database

Comment: Thanks Rick, I followed that tutorial, making sure all the checkboxes had the same name value('reasoN[]'). But it reports the checkboxes as "Array", in the screen output as well as to mysql database